# Would there be a difference if deuterium is embedded instead of protium (regular hydrogen) in acids?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, atoms, analytical-chemistry

So instead of regular hydrogen, it would be a deuterium (still a Hydrogen). For example, instead of $\ce{HCl}$ it would be $\ce{DCl}$ where D is a deuterium.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there would be a difference. The acids would be weaker.  Why? Because the heavier isotope lowers the zero-point energy (the lowest possible energy) in the acid molecule, making the acid's bond to the D stronger than it would have been to the H. Acids in $\rm D_2O$ are weaker than they are in ordinary water, too.

Any reaction that involves dissociation of these acids will run more slowly, too. This is called "the kinetic isotope effect". You can read more about that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_isotope_effect

You might want to ask further questions: *why* is the zero point energy lower for a bond to D than a bond to H? How exactly does the lower zero point energy make the bond stronger? How exactly does it affect the rates of reactions that include acid dissociation?

Ask away!

If you'd like to see how substituting a D for an H in acids affects the acid dissociation constant for particular acids, [here's a good reference](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73A/jresv73An3p299_A1b.pdf):

R. A. Robinson, M. Paabo, R. G. Bates, "Deuterium Isotope Effect on the Dissociation of Weak Acids in Water and Deuterium Oxide", *J. Res. Nat. Bureau. Standards*, **73A(3)**, 1969, pp 299-308.

Comment: That's very interesting - in polymer science we often assume that deuterated species don't affect the chemistry, but from that reference it looks like the pKa can change by about 0.5 - pretty significant for weak acids!

Comment: I added a link to that reference - it's hosted at NIST, so you don't need journal access to read it

Comment: Ha, I just found it online myself and added the link, too. You guys are quick!

Comment: What about the zero point energy of O-H in $\ce{H3O+}$ relative to O-D in $\ce{D3O+}$ ? Why isn't that equally and oppositely important?

Comment: @DavePhD, it will be oppositely but not equally important, because the change in reduced mass on isotopic substitution there isn't as great as it is in the acid, right? Assuming the acid anion has a larger mass than water.

Comment: @FredSenese I guess it would depend on relative bond strengths (hydronium versus the acid) and relative reduced masses.  I just meant equally important to consider, not that the zero point energies themselves were equal.  For HF or NH3 the reduced masses would be similar to water.  Complicated to extend to polyatomics.