# In a jet or internal combustion engine that burns hydrogen as a fuel, what would happen if you replaced the hydrogen with deuterium?

Tags: combustion

Would it increase the power of the jet engine due to heavier atoms being exhausted out the back?

For the same reason would it slow down an internal combustion engine?

Comment: I thought jet engines burn kerosene, and hydrogen is more suited for rockets.

Comment: @andselisk There are several hydrogen powered jets and cars that have been produced.

Comment: I guess you need to specify the exact types of engines you are talking about, and provide some references. I still cannot imagine a jet reaction engine using hydrogen (maybe you meant a turboshaft?), I must be living under a rock. Also, you might want to split the question in two as an internal combustion engine and a reaction engine have fundamentally different operating principles.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to answer your question satisfactorily. Simply mentioning "What will happen..." is rather vague, for there are several things that could happen.

Comment: @Pritt Balagopal Its not very complicated I don't think. Deuterium is a hydrogen atom with double the mass.  I just want to know what effect in theory that should have on an engine burning it.

Comment: Deuterium is not a gas. It is a isotope. Normally it comes as HD gas simply because Deuterium is rather rare is that what you mean. There is not much DD gas.

Comment: `Its not very complicated I don't think. Deuterium is a hydrogen atom with double the mass.` An extra neutron can change many things. An extra neutron made heavy water colorless, while normal water is very light blue. `I just want to know what effect in theory that should have on an engine burning it.` First of all, you must realize that engines are designed based on the fuel it uses. Using $\ce{D2}$ instead of $\ce{H2}$ can cause several problems, and you would need several books that explain the engines functioning to know why. There will be effects of course, just way too many effects.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23831/would-there-be-a-difference-if-deuterium-is-embedded-instead-of-protium-regular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chemical properties of isotopes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/chemical-properties-of-isotopes)

Comment: Very roughly there is nothing to gain. D2 will double the mass of the rocket while providing less energy content (D2 dissociation energy is higher than that of H2).

Comment: Sorry. You asked about jet or IC engines :)) but it should work the same. Momentum and energy counts, at least for jet. In IC again you have a heavier vehicle and less energy inside,   you should both have littler acceleration and lower final attainable speed.